# Javascript Snake Game - too much recursion error

Tags: javascript, recursion

so I'm working on this snake game, and I'm basically trying to prevent the food from spawning on top of the snake tail. My setup variables:

```
let headX = 10; //snake starting position
let headY = 10;

let appleX = 5; //food starting position
let appleY = 5;
```

This is the function that checks head/food collision

```
function checkAppleCollision() {
  if (appleX === headX && appleY === headY) {
    generateApplePosition();
    tailLength++;
    score++;
  }
}
```

And this is the function that randomizes the apple position after collision, and also returns the "too much recursion" error, after a couple of collisions:

```
function generateApplePosition() {
  let collisionDetect = false;
  let newAppleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
  let newAppleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);

  for (let i = 0; i < snakeTail.length; i++) {
    let segment = snakeTail[i];
    if (newAppleX === segment.x && newAppleY === segment.y) {
      collisionDetect = true;
    }
  }
  while (collisionDetect === true) {
    generateApplePosition();
  }
  appleX = newAppleX;
  appleY = newAppleY;
}
```

Please help, I have no idea what to do here. Everything else works as intended.

Comment: Why does this need to be recursive at all?

Comment: I just thought that this might be the way to go, of course it's likely not optimal. I have no previous experience with this type of project, so could you give advice on a better way to type the function?

Comment: 1. The problem doesn't call for recursion at all. You *could* do it but it's a bit superfluous. 2. The code *does not work* for recursion. The point of recursion is iteratively make simpler problems until you get to one that can be solved (the base case) and then iteratively resolve the simplified problems backwards. There is no base case here. There is nothing to stop the recursion. `while (collisionDetect === true)` ensures that if the condition is true, you would *always* get an error. Because the function is recalled infinite times until a recursive call also goes in the `while` etc.

Comment: Your recursion is dependant upon a variable that never gets updated - `collisionDetect` in the called function is completely different from the one in the calling function.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using recursions or `do while` is a bad idea** (I'll explain later)

---

meanwhile, you could simplify your logic by creating:

- reusable `samePos()` and `collides()` functions
- a **recursive** `createApple()` function, which will return itself if the randomly generated x,y positions are occupied by the snake body

```js
const world = {w:6, h:1}; // height set to 1 for this demo only
const snake = [{x:0, y:0}, {x:1, y:0}, {x:2, y:0}, {x:3, y:0}];
const apple = {pos: {x:0, y:0}}; 

// Check if two object's x,y match
const samePos = (a, b) => a.x === b.x && a.y === b.y; 

// Check if object x,y is inside an array of objects
const collides = (ob, arr) => arr.some(o => samePos(ob, o));

const createApple = () => {

  const randPos = {
    x: ~~(Math.random() * world.w),
    y: ~~(Math.random() * world.h),
  };
    
  if (collides(randPos, snake)) {
    console.log(`position ${randPos.x} ${randPos.y} is occupied by snake`);
    return createApple(); // Try another position.
  }
  
  // Finally a free spot!
  apple.pos = randPos;
  console.log(`Apple to free position: ${apple.pos.x} ${apple.pos.y}`);
}

createApple();
```

```html
Run this demo multiple times
```

### The problem

**Useless random guesswork!**
As you can see from the example above, if you run it multiple times, very often the randomly generated number is the same as the previously generated one:

```
...
position 2 0 is occupied by snake    <<<
position 1 0 is occupied by snake
position 2 0 is occupied by snake    <<<
position 2 0 is occupied by snake    <<<
position 1 0 is occupied by snake
position 2 0 is occupied by snake    <<<
...
```

therefore, as your snake grows in size, the recursion might go wild — ad absurdum, iterating way too many times, repeating and failing on the same xy positions, until finally hitting a rare free spot...
**This is a really bad design.**

### Solutions

One solution would be to keep track of the already used randomized positions inside an Array - but that implies unnecessarily to go trough such an Array.

**A best solution** would be to actually treat the game not as a **2D game**, but as a **1D game**:

Consider this 2D map of size 4x3 **as indexes**:

```
0  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11
```

now, let's place a snake into this map:

```
0  ⬛  2  3
4  ⬛  ⬛  7
8  9  ⬛  11
```

here's the linear map with the Snake as a 1D list:

```
[ 0  ⬛  2  3  4  ⬛  ⬛  7  8  9  ⬛  11 ]
```

therefore, instead of using an array of objects `{x:n, y:n}` for the snake body positions, all you need is:

```js
[1, 5, 6, 10]  // Snake body as indexes
```

Now that you know all the indexes where you're not allowed to place an Apple, all you need to do when creating the new apple is:

- Create an Array of *0-N* indexes of length: world.w * world.h
- Loop the snake body indexes and `delete` those indexes from the array of indexes to get an **Array of free spots indexes**
- Simply **get only once a random key from that array of free spots!**

```js
const indexToXY = (index, width) => ({ x: index%width, y: Math.trunc(index/width) });

const world = {w:4, h:3};
const snakeBody = [1, 5, 6, 10];

const createApple = () => {
  const arr = [...Array(world.w * world.h).keys()]; // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
  snakeBody.forEach(i => delete arr[i]); 
  const freeIndexes = arr.filter(k => k !== undefined); // [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11]
  const appleIndex = freeIndexes[~~(Math.random() * freeIndexes.length)];
  const applePos = indexToXY(appleIndex, world.w);
  console.log("New apple position: %o", applePos);
};

createApple();
```

```html
Run this demo multiple times
```

Having that free spot index simply draw your apple at the XY coordinates using this simple formula

X  =  *index % mapWidth*
Y  =  *floor(index / mapWidth)*

Comment: Wow, what an elaborate and informative answer. I'll study it thoroughly, thanks for the information! The game seems to be working as intended now, but I'll take your advice and try to implement what you pointed out here.

Comment: @EddieBenzon  Thx. Certainly! As a nice homework you could try one day to remake the same game to a linear 1D (using indexes). The only tougher task will be converting the key directions to the appropriate N,S,E,W index (with some basic math). The rest is pretty simple. Even if you create your game using DIV elements in a grid it's easier to color specific DIV elements using those indexes. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this doesn't need to be recursive, and you should also take into account the (however unlikely) possibility where there are no more tiles to spawn on which would result in an infinite loop.

```
function generateApplePosition() {
    // Count how many tiles are left for spawning in
    const tilesLeft = (tileCount * tileCount) - snakeTail.length;
    let collisionDetect;
    
    if (tilesLeft > 0) {
        do {
            const newAppleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
            const newAppleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
            collisionDetect = false;
            
            for (let i = 0; i < snakeTail.length; i++) {
                const { x, y } = snakeTail[i];
                if (newAppleX === x && newAppleY === y) {
                    collisionDetect = true; // Collision
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (!collisionDetect) {
                // Found spawn point
                appleX = newAppleX;
                appleY = newAppleY;
            }
        } while (collisionDetect);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (tilesLeft > 0) {` makes no sense. If no tiles are left that's part of a `isGameOver()` logic. A function that generates the apple position should not be concerned about irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Agreed, however since none of the rest of the game logic was presented, in this context it is a legitimate concern to avoid an infinite loop.